# Magento at root with a flipbook on subdomain 404 unless using index.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento

Running Magento 1.7 multisite (4 "websites") as follows:

```
example.com
ca.example.com
example.com/b2b
ca.example.com/b2b
```

These "websites" are working fine and I am limited in my knowledge of .htaccess, so I don't want to mess with it until I have a better idea of what the problem may be. Added a "Flipbook" in a subdirectory. Throws 404 from apache unless I use `example.com/flipbook/index.html` and need it to load with just `example.com/flipbook/`

Can you help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to use is `DirectoryIndex` from [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html). Basically it will let you specify what files to open by default if you have not specifed a file in your request.

```
<Directory /flipbook>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</Directory>
```